# Save Settings in Dependent Dll

Tags: c#, dll, settings

I have a Windows Service and a dependent Dll, I chose this way so that Dll can be invoked by any application, Winforms, WPF etc.

Now I am stumped on what is the best practice to Save settings in the Dll, I used User Settings in the dll and Saved them from calling App.

```
public class Preferences
{
    public static string IPAddress
    {
        get { return Settings.Default.IPAddress; }
        set { Settings.Default.IPAddress = value; }
    }
}
```

and then in my service/Winforms Code, I wrote

```
Preferences.IPAddress = "XX.XX.XX.XX"
```

Someone told me this is not how you should do it . I wanted to know is this not the correct approach

Comment: Did they give a reason?

Comment: It won't work if that service runs on a server that has many client connections but it should work if it runs on all client machines. There are ways to get the IP address of the PC if that is what you are doing.

Comment: @ Crowcoder, There are many other settings too , This IP address is just an example of big settings file.

Comment: I'd pick a more mainstream example to illustrate the question if I were you, such as a string or int property. The IP Address example looks a bit fishy. In general terms, what you're doing seems fine. The settings will be stored in .config and you get a nice strongly typed Settings class to use.

Comment: @ Rowland Shaw, They mentioned that this approach cant be used with the service as I am violating Windows security policy with the User settings